# Under what conditions does flush() need to be invoked in an Ecto migration?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to figure out what kind of situation would require using flush.

As a counter example, this (trivial) situation does not require flush :

```
defmodule MyRepo.Migrations.TestFlush do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:test)
    alter table(:test) do
      add :a, :integer
    end
  end
end
```

It works both "forwards" and "backwards" using `ecto.migrate` and `ecto.rollback` respectively.  The second macro "alter table" is dependent on the first macro "create table" completing.  flush() is not required to indicate any sort of synchronous dependency here.

I'm trying to define situations where flush() is required to be invoked in order for a particular migration to run successfully.

Here's the docs for flush : 
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#flush/0

Here's the source code for flush : 
https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/migration/runner.ex#L96

Note the source code for flush reverses the "commands", but it doesn't define what constitutes a command.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to use flush, e.g. when your migration after flush (`M2`) depends on migrations before flush (`M1`). To be clear, `M1` and `M2` are both part of the same migration file and both are defined and executed within `change/0`.

Let's say `M1` creates a table, adds columns to the database and inserts some data that are part of your migration code. `M2` then queries the table and columns from `M1` and generates a new table with the same data. Then, if you don't run `flush/0` between `M1` and `M2`, you cannot perform a query on the column of `M1` since the migration is not executed yet.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the term "queries",  "M2 then queries...".   Because there are multiple ways to run a query, e.g. the migration macro `execute`, and also the Ecto.Repo methods.

Comment: What I mean with "`M2` then queries" is that `M2` executes `SELECT * FROM ...` and inserts the resulting data in a new table that is generated with `create table(:tableName) do ... end`. This is a very simplified example just to illustrate a simple use-case for `flush/0`.
You should also take a look at this thread: https://elixirforum.com/t/using-flush-in-ecto-migration/11720

Comment: This works without flush :   

def change do
    create table(:test)
    alter table(:test) do
      add :a, :integer
    end
    execute """
    select * from test;
    """

Comment: Please check out this article, there is a better example but the problem is nearly identical: https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/ecto-migrations-simple-to-complex

Comment: I think flush() is required because the macros, `alter`, `create`, and even `execute`, all push statements into one transaction queue that will happen later.   By using the Ecto.Repo api functions, those happen "now" which is too early because the transaction has not yet been executed.   However, just from doing some manual testing, it does look like you can invoke any query within an `execute` statement and it should occur in the order you would expect it to.

Comment: We tend to use flush when we add a new column which adheres to some constraints. First we add the column, then we flush, then we perform logic to fill the column with necessary data which adheres to the constraints, after that we finally add the constraints.

Comment: If the migrations only use "commands" from the Ecto.Migration api I don't think you ever need to use `flush`,  all "commands" should all be pushed into a transaction and executed in the order they are defined.    If you use the Ecto.Repo api in a migration file then you likely need `flush()`,  since it will not be executed in the order it was defined ( it will happen before the transaction is run ).